# Null Identity Token Using AuthorizeRequest & AuthorizeResponse

Tags: identityserver4

I'm trying to use use AuthorizeRequest and AuthorizeResponse inside an MVC action to see if the user is already authenticated, but pretty much everything in the response object comes back null besides Raw, Scope, and State.  IsError is false.

I have an Application A and an Application B.  I want to know in Application A if the user already signed in for Application B.

```
        var request = new AuthorizeRequest("https://localhost:5000/connect/authorize");

        var url = request.CreateAuthorizeUrl(
            clientId: "Portal-Local",
            scope: "openid profile email",
            responseType: OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.IdToken,
            responseMode: OidcConstants.ResponseModes.FormPost,
            redirectUri: "https://localhost/Portal/home/index",
            state: CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId(),
            nonce: CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId());

        var response = new AuthorizeResponse(url);

        var accessToken = response.AccessToken;
        var idToken = response.IdentityToken;
        var state = response.State;
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue using the client sample.  I opened up an issue on the IS4 Git.

Comment: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1097